# How to create a plugin for real time collaboration and define custom user in ckeditor in angular

Tags: angular, pdf, plugins, ckeditor, export-to-pdf

we have created a custom build for ckeditor features and I have to add the real time collaboration feature there and import the custom build in our angular code base. when adding just the default plugin and trying to set the user using userPlugin.defineme(user). and getting error '(index):329 There was a problem initializing the editor. CKEditorError: users-me-already-defined'

I am expecting a custom plugin kind of solution for this problem